# Using bootstrap grid: I can't get my images to be the same size and fill their container (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to stack 2 column rows with and image in one of the columns and text in the other alternating for each different row. I have not been able to get my pictures to fill the container they are in. I am also unable to make them the same size (I have been able to make the top picture fill its container).

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ESQ_Main.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <title>ESQ BUILDS:RESIDENTIAL</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class = "col-md-2">
                        </div>
                         <div class = "col-md-2">
                            <a class="btn" href="https://www.google.com/">Home</a>
                         </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <a class="btn" href="https://www.google.com/">About</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "col-md-2">
                            <a class="btn" href="https://www.google.com/">Services</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <a class="btn" href="https://www.google.com/">Conact Us</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                    </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="header_r">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="head">
                  <h1>
                      RESIDENTIAL
                  </h1>
                </div> 
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="label">
            <div class="container">
              <h2>
                Open Projects
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div>  

          <div class="project">
            <div class = "container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-9">
                  <h3>
                    Nantucket
                  </h3>
                  <h5>
                  </h5>
                  <a href="">
                    VIEW
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-9">
                  <a href="https://www.google.com/"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://esqbuilds.com/images/new-galleria-area-townhomes.jpg"></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="project">
            <div class = "container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-9">
                    <a href="https://www.google.com/"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://esqbuilds.com/images/new-galleria-area-townhomes.jpg"></a>           
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-9">
                  <h3>
                    Nantucket
                  </h3>
                  <h5>
                  </h5>
                  <a href="">
                    VIEW
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> 

          <div class="label">
            <div class="container">
              <h2>
                Past Projects
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div> 

          <div class="project">
            <div class = "container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-9">
                  <h3>
                    PAST PROJECT
                  </h3>
                  <h5>
                  </h5>
                  <a href="">
                    VIEW
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-9">
                  <a href="https://www.google.com/"><img class="img-    responsive" src="http://esqbuilds.com/images/new-galleria-area-townhomes.jpg"></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </body>
      </html>

html,body{
                margin:0;
                background-color:#CDB389;
            }
            /*This code is for a different html page. Look under the 
            Residential heading at the bottom of this code*/
            /*HOME HOME HOME HOME HOME HOME HOME HOME HOME*/

            /*MENU*/
            .menu{
                width:100%;
                height:50px;
                background-color:#CDB389;
                text-align:center;
                margin-bottom:0px;
                padding-top:-3px;
            }
            .menu .row{
              padding-top:5px;
              padding-bottom:10px;

            }

            .menu .btn{
              color:black;
              font-size:20px;
              font-weight:900;
            }

            /*HEADER*/
            .header{
              height:600px;
              background:url("http://esqbuilds.com/images/luxury-builder-    houston2.jpg");
              background-size:cover;
              margin-top:-2px;
              margin-bottom:-10px;
            }

            /*LABEL*/
            .label{
                margin-top:-5px;
                background-color:#CDB389;

            }
            .label h2{
                letter-spacing:15px;
                font-size:60px;
                text-decoration:uppercase;
                font-family:cursive;
                color:black;

            }
            /*Services*/

            #extend{
                padding-bottom:50px;
            }
            /*FOOTER*/


            /*BUTTON*/
            .btn:link{
                text-decoration:none
            }
            .btn:hover{

            }

            /*RESIDENTIAL RESIDENTIAL RESIDENTIAL RESIDENTIAL*/

            .head {
                text-align:center;
            }
            .project .row {
                width:100%;
            }
            .project img {
                min-height:300px;
                min-width:400px;
            }


                html,body{
                margin:0;
                background-color:#CDB389;
            }
            /*This code is for a different html page. Look under the 
            Residential heading at the bottom of this code*/
            /*HOME HOME HOME HOME HOME HOME HOME HOME HOME*/

            /*MENU*/
            .menu{
                width:100%;
                height:50px;
                background-color:#CDB389;
                text-align:center;
                margin-bottom:0px;
                padding-top:-3px;
            }
            .menu .row{
              padding-top:5px;
              padding-bottom:10px;

            }

            .menu .btn{
              color:black;
              font-size:20px;
              font-weight:900;
            }

            /*HEADER*/
            .header{
              height:600px;
              background:url("http://esqbuilds.com/images/luxury-builder-houston2.jpg");
              background-size:cover;
              margin-top:-2px;
              margin-bottom:-10px;
            }

            /*LABEL*/
            .label{
                margin-top:-5px;
                background-color:#CDB389;

            }
            .label h2{
                letter-spacing:15px;
                font-size:60px;
                text-decoration:uppercase;
                font-family:cursive;
                color:black;

            }
            /*Services*/

            #extend{
                padding-bottom:50px;
            }
            /*FOOTER*/


            /*BUTTON*/
            .btn:link{
                text-decoration:none
            }
            .btn:hover{

            }

            /*RESIDENTIAL RESIDENTIAL RESIDENTIAL RESIDENTIAL*/

            .head {
                text-align:center;
            }
            .project .row {
                width:100%;
            }
            .project img {
                min-height:300px;
                min-width:400px;
            }
```

Comment: Be consistent, in first project you use `container-fluid`, in the second you use `container` and in the past project your class in `img` element is `img-    responsive` which is not good (remove spaces between `img` and `responsive`.

Comment: I'm new to this and not sure I am understanding the difference between container-fluid and container even after reading some explanations. Could you explain the difference?

Comment: Best way is to read Bootstrap docs. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the images in a div with the `overflow:hidden;` and set the `width:100%; height:auto;`

Alternatively you could set your images to be the background image and set them to `background-size:cover;` this will be responsive.

Comment: For some reason setting the image as the background has not been working. I also tried wrapping the images in divs and that has not worked either because overflow causes half of the picture to be hidden. Any other ideas?

Comment: Gorg he is not using backgrund image in rows and cols. So, there is no point of background.

Comment: @AlejandroEsquino if you change the image to a background the div will no longer have any content therefore it become 0px by 0px. You therefore will need to give the div that contains the background image a height and width that you would like the images to be. If it is inside of a container that has the correct dimensions you can just set it to 100% by 100%.

I'e taken the liberty of making a JSfiddle that you can add to.  [link](https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=MNoAvOLKuK)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! So, I added the class:

```
size{
 max-width:500px
 height:auto;
}
```

Then I wrapped each of my images in a link and added the img-responsive class to the image.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-9">
  <a class"size" href="https://www.google.com/">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="http://esqbuilds.com/images/new-galleria-area-townhomes.jpg"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

This gives me the full image on one side of the screen and allows room for text on the other side. It also keeps the image within the width of the screen. Additionally, it stacks relatively nicely when the screen is shrunk (the stack could be a bit more even/centered). Still have to check mobile responsiveness.

I am so happy.